# ECU after engine swap

Tags: engine, electronic-control-module, swap

I have a 2005 wrx, previous owner engine swapped it to the STI short block (EJ257) so now it’s a 2.5 instead of a 2.0, i’m trying to buy an accessport for it, but i don’t know which one to get because i don’t know if it’s the sti 2.5 ECU or the wrx 2.0 ECU.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Pull the ECU (which I believe should be under a plate under the passenger's feet) and get the part number off of it. Use that to cross reference to what you need as far as the accessport for it goes. I'm sure the company who sells the accessport will give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Like paul said, pull up the passenger side carpet, the ECU is under a metal plate. Grab the number off of it to cross reference and youll be good to go. You can even send that number to Cobb and they will make sure youre squared away with what you need.